# Customizing WebTaggingDialog.JS file on SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When I open dialog that edits metadata of a SharePoint2010 object, I see that the web page loads various JavaScript files. One of them is `WebTaggingDialog.JS`. I need to customize functions in this JavaScript file.

1. Does anybody know if this is a static file that comes somewhere from the server?
2. Is there any SharePoint feature that forces this file to be generated on the fly and/or influence its content?

Can anybody confirm that this is not possible at all?